# andorid kotlin - how to downcast a synthetic view import

Tags: android, kotlin

Let me show you my xml file what it looks like so you understand what i need done.

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    fresco:actualImageScaleType="none"
    fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="center"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/spinner"/>

</merge>
```

when i was using butterknife i imported this view like this:

```
 @BindView(R.id.iv)
    DraweeView iv; //this
```

Notice how in butter knife i can assign it to the BASE CLASS of SimpleDraweeView.  and there was never any issue.

But now i have converted my file to kotlin and its assigning the iv like this:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.mylayout.view.iv
```

and then when i check the class type of iv its not the super class type, its type is SimpleDraweeView . i want it to be DraweeView. i guess that would be expected. but how do i make it so kotlin uses the super class of SimpleDraweeView.

I tried casting the view but then i always have to cast it when i use it. is there a way to do it like butterknife does ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure help you, 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/198

Refer it, or you must be create new var for super class, I guess